# openapi-generator-maven-plugin code gen from http

Tags: swagger, swagger-codegen, swagger-codegen-maven-plugin, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

Can we pass input yml specification HTTP URL in openapi-generator-maven-plugin?

I wanted to keep the input specification and generated code in sync.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, with *openapi-generator-maven-plugin* that is possible by simply giving URL including protocol as `inputSpec`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
    <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            ...
            <configuration>
                <inputSpec>https://petstore3.swagger.io/api/v3/openapi.yaml</inputSpec>
                ...
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Updating plugin version might be necessary.

Comment: how to pass the bitbucket url which needs auth token?